# How to get default style flex in css

Tags: .net, apache-flex, styles

We have a requirement to create a few web pages in .NET that will be hosted in an existing flex site. Now we need to follow the look and feel of that flex site.
When we tried to get the style information we were left with very little options. We were told there is no stylesheet used. It's just the default flex styles. Now here is my question,
is there a way to get the default style of flex controls in a css file?

Comment: Which version of Flex is being used?  Most likely they are using either Halo styles in Flex 3 branch, or Spark styles in the Flex 4 branch.  I don't believe either of these visual styles are entirely CSS based; and even if they were I would not expect that CSS to work with HTML pages.

Comment: You can find the CSS files for both Spark and Halo styles in the Flex SDK, however they contain a lot of references to skinClasses which would be useless to you.

Answer (score 0):

If I wanted to look at the default for mx on my machine, I would find it here
C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.5\sdks\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\mx

If you are using Spark or a theme you will need to go up level and start looking there.